# Spring boot hibernate transaction management

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I want to handle the transaction at service layer by hibernate with springbbot as below . Transaction are not getting committed . I do not want transaction to be handled by spring data jpa. it should be done by hibernate. what is wrong with

AppConfig.java

```
    package com
    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com" })
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com" })
    @EntityScan(basePackages = { "com" })
    @EnableTransactionManagement

    public class AppConfig {
        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;

        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com");
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

            return txManager;
        }

    }
```

Service layer

```
    package com.codeatomic.springbootquickstart.topic;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    @Service
    public class TopicService {

        @Autowired
        private TopicRepository dao;

    @Transactional
        public Topic getTopicHibernate() {
            Topic topic=new Topic("spring", "Spring Framework", "Spring framework description.");
            //transactionManager.co
            return dao.saveTopic(topic);
            //int i=1/0;

            //topic=new Topic("java", "Core Java", "Core Java description.");


        //  dao.saveTopic(topic);
            //return dao.getTopic();
        }


    }
```

Dao Layer

```
    package com.codeatomic.springbootquickstart.topic;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    @Component
    public class TopicDao {
        @Autowired
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public Topic  saveTopic(Topic t) {
            t.setId("20");
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            //t= this.getTopic();
             //Transaction tx;
             //tx = session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(t);
            //tx.commit();

            System.out.println(t);
            return t;

        }

    }
```

Topic.java

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="topic")
public class Topic implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 865790868118561501L;
@Id
private String id;
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
@Column(name="description")
private String description;
```

Please help . what is wrong with above code

Comment: Have you tried to put the @Transactional above TopicDao class?

Comment: I put it above service layer . I want to handle the transaction at service layer not dao

Comment: What is the stack trace or error log? Can you share your Topic class? You are setting id externally. Does it has auto increment field? If id is auto increment and id field then it will not allow to set id externally

Comment: Yes, but you do not have a session in your service layer. Try to open the session in service layer and pass it in you DAO.

Comment: adding @Transactional at dao not working either

Comment: There is no error but transaction not getting committed